# Webcam not working on desktop with failed to allocate required memory

Tags: webcam, gstreamer

I have a nexigo hd webcam that works on my work laptop (running Ubuntu), but which fails on my desktop (also running Ubuntu).  I'm sure I've got something misconfigured on my desktop, but I'm at a loss as to what to check next.

I've tried various web browsers, cheese, qv4l2, obs-studio, and gst-launch-1.0.  This is a standard desktop with a USB webcam, so no special keys to press to enable the camera and no physical switches.  It's just an unplug/plug between my laptop and desktop between tests.  It's unlikely to be related, but my desktop is using AMD graphics.  This is on bare metal, no virtualization, docker, snap, flatpak, etc.  At least, not that I can see.

The following are all from my desktop, where the webcam is not working.  I'm in the video group:

```
└──> ls -l /dev/video*
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Oct 20 16:10 /dev/video0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 Oct 20 16:10 /dev/video1
└──> groups | grep -o video
video
```

The device is found:

```
└──> v4l2-ctl --list-devices
NexiGo N60 FHD Webcam: NexiGo N (usb-0000:0c:00.3-3.1.2):
        /dev/video0
        /dev/video1
        /dev/media0
```

It's a relatively standard uvcvideo device:

```
└──> v4l2-dbg -D -d /dev/video0   
Driver info:
        Driver name   : uvcvideo
        Card type     : NexiGo N60 FHD Webcam: NexiGo N
        Bus info      : usb-0000:0c:00.3-3.1.2
        Driver version: 6.2.16
        Capabilities  : 0x84A00001
                Video Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
                Device Capabilities
```

But I can't allocate buffers.  I assume the problem is the same with other programs, but I can't always get nice logs.

```
└──> GST_DEBUG="v4l2*:3" gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoscale ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
0:00:00.079505628 31240 0x564e88fc6800 ERROR         v4l2bufferpool gstv4l2bufferpool.c:706:gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_streamon:<v4l2src0:pool0:src> error with STREAMON 5 (Input/output error)
0:00:00.079591570 31240 0x564e88fc6800 WARN                 v4l2src gstv4l2src.c:759:gst_v4l2src_decide_allocation:<v4l2src0> error: Failed to allocate required memory.
0:00:00.079597662 31240 0x564e88fc6800 WARN                 v4l2src gstv4l2src.c:759:gst_v4l2src_decide_allocation:<v4l2src0> error: Buffer pool activation failed
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Failed to allocate required memory.
Additional debug info:
../sys/v4l2/gstv4l2src.c(759): gst_v4l2src_decide_allocation (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
Buffer pool activation failed
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
../libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c(3127): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
Execution ended after 0:00:00.059204336
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Looking at an strace of the above, I'm getting `EIO` from an `ioctl` for `VIDIOC_STREAMON`.

```
34265 ioctl(7, VIDIOC_REQBUFS, {type=V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE, memory=V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP, count=2 => 2}) = 0
34265 ioctl(7, VIDIOC_QUERYBUF, {type=V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE, index=0, memory=V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP, m.offset=0, length=1843200, bytesused=0, flags=V4L2_BUF_FLAG_TIMESTAMP_MONOTONIC|V4L2_BUF_FLAG_TSTAMP_SRC_SOE, ...}) = 0
34265 ioctl(7, VIDIOC_QUERYBUF, {type=V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE, index=1, memory=V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP, m.offset=0x1c2000, length=1843200, bytesused=0, flags=V4L2_BUF_FLAG_TIMESTAMP_MONOTONIC|V4L2_BUF_FLAG_TSTAMP_SRC_SOE, ...}) = 0
34265 ioctl(7, VIDIOC_EXPBUF, 0x7f0445e3da10) = 0
34265 futex(0x7f04486e10a8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
34265 ioctl(7, VIDIOC_QBUF, {type=V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE, index=0, memory=V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP, m.offset=0, length=1843200, bytesused=0, flags=V4L2_BUF_FLAG_MAPPED|V4L2_BUF_FLAG_QUEUED|V4L2_BUF_FLAG_TIMESTAMP_MONOTONIC|V4L2_BUF_FLAG_TSTAMP_SRC_SOE, ...}) = 0
34265 futex(0x7f043800c628, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
34265 ioctl(7, VIDIOC_EXPBUF, 0x7f0445e3da10) = 0
34265 ioctl(7, VIDIOC_QBUF, {type=V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE, index=1, memory=V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP, m.offset=0x1c2000, length=1843200, bytesused=0, flags=V4L2_BUF_FLAG_MAPPED|V4L2_BUF_FLAG_QUEUED|V4L2_BUF_FLAG_TIMESTAMP_MONOTONIC|V4L2_BUF_FLAG_TSTAMP_SRC_SOE, ...}) = 0
34265 futex(0x7f043800c628, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
34265 ioctl(13, VIDIOC_STREAMON, [V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE]) = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
```

This is where I get stuck.  What should I be looking at next?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured this out.  The detail I omitted was that the camera is going through a kvm hdmi/usb2.0 hub.  I found the uvcvideo FAQ (https://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/faq/) which pointed me at the possibility of not enough USB bandwidth.  That appears to be the issue.  When I bypass the kvm by plugging directly into my desktop, then the webcam works.  If I swap the kvm ports, then my desktop works and my laptop doesn't.

You can see this in lsusb:

```
└──> lsusb -t
/:  Bus 06.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
/:  Bus 05.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 41, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 12M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 45, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 45, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 12M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 45, If 3, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 45, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 12M
...truncated...
```

Here it is after swapping the kvm ports (and the webcam working on my desktop):

```
└──> lsusb -t
/:  Bus 06.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
/:  Bus 05.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 56, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 59, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 60, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 60, If 3, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 60, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 60, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
```

Hopefully this helps someone else.